# Add Custom Actions to a Record List Page

Tags: lightning, custom-object, lightning-experience, custom-actions, lightning-builder

I have the need to add custom actions on the Record List Pages from our objects and I cannot be able to find anything related to this and I'm just wondering if it's possible.
[image]

Only we have `New` and `Import` actions, and I would like to have custom ones in this page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need a Custom List Button for this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_custom_button.htm (the examples are shown in Salesforce Classic, but it works similarly in Lightning Experience)

Note: your custom buttons will **not** appear on the 'Recently Viewed' list - they are only available on one of the actual list views for that object.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Custom List Buttons are really limited ---
1)  Actions which are type: lightning component are not available to add on the "Search Layout" tab for the object (others like "update a record" it is to be added as QuickActions)
 ---- 2) Custom List Buttons can't be overridden by a lightning component (only is available URL, onClick Javascript & VisualForce Page)
-----------
I can go though step 2 but I can't be able to see any visualforce page available for it - always is empty list - but beside this, I don't like the idea to add lightning components on visualforce pages.

Comment: re: 2) your visualforce has to have a standard list controller matching the object you want to use it on, i.e.: standard controller for the same object and the `recordSetVar` attribute set.